# C# - Constrain an argument to be an instance of Type

Tags: c#, types, constraints

I want to create a `Dictionary` that maps a `Type` to an `Action`, but I want the keys to be types that come from a specific parent class. So I want to do something like:

```
class Container
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Action> dict;

    public void AddAction(Type t, Action a) where t : typeof(SomeParentClass)
    {
        dict[t] = a;
    }
}
```

Where the `AddAction` method only accepts values of `t` that are types of classes that are subclasses of some specific class. I've seen something like this done in Java with the `extends` keyword, but I can't figure out how to do this in C#, if it's even possible.

Edit: To clarify, I don't want the AddAction method to take an instance of SomeParentClass, but rather the Type of a class that is a subclass of SomeParentClass. Is there maybe a better way than using Types?

Edit: What I'm essentially trying to do is create a dispatching service, wherein various parts of the app can register interest in an Event type and provide an Action that is called when an event of that type is fired. So imagine something like

```
service.RegisterInterest(typeof(MyEvent), myAction)
```

Where `myAction` is of type `Action<MyEvent>` (something I didn't put in the original post but should have instead of a plain `Action`).

Then some other part of the app can do

```
service.TriggerEvent(typeof(MyEvent))
```

Which causes all `Action<MyEvent>` instances registered as above to be called...So in fact that `Dictionary` maps a `Type` to a `List<Action<Event>>`, not a single `Action`.

Comment: If you show us how you're using it, we may be able to come up with more appropriate solutions

Comment: I updated my post to provide some more details.

Comment: With those new details, it seems like you want compile-time checking. I think this makes the first part of Lee's answer perfect for you. You would just type `RegisterInterest<MyEvent>(myAction)` and `TriggerEvent<MyEvent>()` then.

Comment: It's getting there, but now I'm having trouble making it take an Action<T> instead of a plain Action...the Dictionary needs to hold a List<Action<Event>>, but it seems I can't call RegisterInterest with an instance of Action<MyEvent>. Is this a covariance thing that C# (at least 3.5) just can't do?

Comment: Try casting it to `Action<Event>` when you put it on the list. Then, when triggering, you can cast it back to `Action<MyEvent>` because you do know what type it is (the key of the dictionary entry, also the type parameter to `Trigger`). Since it's internal like that, it's a perfectly fine use of casting.

Comment: The first cast works, but it won't compile casting back, saying I can't convert Action<Event> to Action<T> (where T is a subclass of Event, which I've got in a where constraint in the TriggerEvent method where the Action is invoked).

Comment: A few things are unclear here. Why do you want a list of Action<Event> while you expect the usage to be RegisterInterest<MyEvent>(Action<MyEvent>) (or Action<any other derived class>). Action<MyEvent> methods will take a parameter of type MyEvent and you will not be able to invoke any such method by passing a param of type Event (derived class can not hold a ref to base class) which you will be required to if you use Action<Event> (and hence Action<MyEvent> can not be cast to Action<Event>). Can you clarify your question what exactly you want i.e How you plan to use your Action<Event> list?

Answer (score 6):

If you require compile-time checking you can use generics:

```
public void AddAction<T>(Action a) where T : SomeParentClass
{
    dict[typeof(T)] = a;
}
```

You may also want to keep the non-generic version

```
public void AddAction(Type t, Action a)
{
    if(! typeof(SomeClass).IsAssignableFrom(t)) throw new ArgumentException();
    dict[t] = a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with something like this:

```
class Container
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Action> dict;

    public bool AddAction(Type t, Action a) 
    {
        if (typeof(SomeParentClass).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        { 
            dict[t] = a;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `t` and `typeof(SomeParentClass)` need to be swapped in the if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Type t`, use `SomeParentClass t` as param

Answer (score 0):

Add assertion to the method.

```
Debug.Assert(t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(SomeParentClass)));
```